# What is the best algorithm to match two people based on their radiuses and the distance between them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algorithm, google-maps, geometry

I have two models in my rails application: student and tutor. Each model has their own location attributes: latitude, longitude, radius(the radius is input by student/tutor since they decide how far they wanna meet to learn or teach). The latitude and longitude are decided by Google api, and I can get the distance between them with the API also. 
Let call the distance between them is distance, r1 for the radius of the student, and r2 for the radius of the tutor.
Now my job is to match the student and tutor that can satisfy the condition r1 and r2. I've come up with the solution:

```
match tutor and student if distance - r1 - r2 <= 0
```

However, I am not sure about the accurate of my solution even though I think that algorithm covers all the cases:

1. Both circles have one common point.
2. Both circles have 2 common points.
3. One of the circles is inside of the other.

I think this is not a difficult problem, but I haven't touched geometry for a while since high school, so any advice here would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not `distance <= min{r1,r2}` ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DanielWagner, I've just edited the question. Thanks for the remind.

Comment: I still don't see a question...

Comment: @amit, distance <= min{r1, r2} won't satisfy if their position is secant right?

Comment: Your method is geometrically correct, but this is not really a programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry, not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

You also need the position `x` of both objects, not only the radii `r`.

Then both circles intersect when

```
dx = x1 - x2
dy = y1 - y2
dz = z1 - z2
sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz) <= r1 + r2
```

The rest is simple.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, could you please explain a bit how did you come up with the solution or point me the right source?

Comment: it is basic geometry. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html . It will depend whether your are in 3D or 2D.

Comment: Ok, I am gonna take a look at it. Have a great day. :)